# Exception in a Hello World webmethod

Tags: .net, web-services

I get an exception in a WS (asmx) which says:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerType..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

I am invoking the method from the browser and it's a `HelloWorld()` web method that does not do anything

Comment: Even though the webmethod is not doing anything, I would include the definition, as well as more details on how you are invoking it.

Comment: Can you post your source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was really messed up in my web service code. I deleted the project, recreated it, everything works fine. Sorry!